# How do I use Windows MouseKeys with Modern apps?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, accessibility

I've enabled [mouse keys](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/use-mouse-keys-to-move-the-mouse-pointer) in my Windows 8 installation, and I've noticed that some modern apps don't properly respond to the mouse events.

For instance, the Netflix and Mint apps don't receive the mouse-over and mouse-click events through mouse keys, where as Skype and others do.  All apps behave as expected with real mouse input.

Is there something I need to configure in Windows to make this work properly for all modern apps, or are the apps themselves lacking a proper implementation?